# How does commit_on_success handle being nested?

Tags: database, django, django-orm

I'm a bit confused about how I should handle transactions in a particular situation.

I've got some code that boils down to this:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_on_success
def process_post():
    #do stuff with database
    for reply in post_replies:
        process_post_reply(reply)

@transaction.commit_on_success
def process_post_reply(reply):
    #do stuff with database
```

I want to know what happens if a `process_post_reply()` fails.

How does commit_on_success handle being nested? Will it understand to commit each `process_post_reply()` or if one fails the whole `process_post()` rolls back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the source code of it: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.2.4/django/db/transaction.py#L286

And [enter_transaction_management](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.2.4/django/db/transaction.py#L46) is as simple as putting new transaction handling mode on the thread stack.

So, in your case, if `process_post_reply()` fails (i.e. exception occurs), then the transaction is rolled back in its entirety, and then the exception propagates upwards from `process_post()` as well but there is nothing to roll back.

And no, if one `process_post_reply()` fails then the whole `process_post()` is not being rolled back - there's no magic there, only COMMIT and ROLLBACK on the database level, which means that what gets rolled back is only what has been written to the DB after the last commited `process_post_reply()`.

Summarizing, **I think that what you need** is just a single `commit_on_success()` around `process_post`, possibly supported by [transaction savepoints](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints) - which unfortunately are available only in PostgreSQL backend, even though MySQL 5.x supports them as well.

**EDIT 10 Apr 2012**: Savepoint support for MySQL is now [available in Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints)

**EDIT 2 Jul 2014**: Transaction management has been completely rewritten in Django 1.6 - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/ and `commit_on_success` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

To gain more control on the transaction management, it's good to use `transaction.commit_manually()`:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def process_post(reply):
    do_stuff_with_database()
    for reply in post_replies:
        process_post_reply(transaction_commit_on_success=False)

def process_post_reply(reply, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('transaction_commit_on_success', True):
        with transaction.commit_manually():
            try:
                do_stuff_with_database()
            except Exception, e:
                transaction.rollback()
                raise e
            else:
                transaction.commit()
    else:
        do_stuff_with_database()
```

Here you can decide depending on circumstances, commit transaction or not.